# FormControl.Validators.pattern does not work correctly, while Regex with same string shows that data matches

Tags: angular, regex, typescript, angular-custom-validators

I am trying to create pattern for phone numbers and I want to look it like this:

1. +375 29 555 55 55
2. 80-33-555-555-55
3. +375-25-555-55-55
4. 80445555555
   etc.

I wrote following code:

.ts

```
  phoneFormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^\s*(\+375|80)\s?-?\s?(25|29|33|44)\s?-?\s?\d{3}\s?-?\s?\d{2}\s?-?\s?\d{2}$')]);
```

.html

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <mat-label>Телефон</mat-label>
      <input matInput [(ngModel)]="this.profileData.Phone" [formControl]="phoneFormControl" maxlength="30">
      <mat-error *ngIf="phoneFormControl.hasError('pattern')">Номер не соответствует формату!</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
```

But i have error:
[image]

A also tried to change .ts to this `phoneFormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^\s*80\s?-?\s?(25|29|33|44)\s?-?\s?\d{3}\s?-?\s?\d{2}\s?-?\s?\d{2}$')]);`
expecting that it will be work only with 80...
Error disappeared, but it does not work correctly now (I used 80295555555 80-29-555-55-55 80 33 555 55 55)...

Also I have tried this:

```
 phoneFormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('/^\s*([+]{1}375|80)\s?-?\s?(25|29|33|44)\s?-?\s?\d{3}\s?-?\s?\d{2}\s?-?\s?\d{2}$/')]);
```

What can I do to get expected result?

Answer (score -2):

I'm not under 100% sure, but it seems that you have a typo.

If you check the example in the [official documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#pattern), you see that you don't need `^` and `$` at the beginning and end of your regex string.

So, probably, you just need to change your code to this:

```
phoneFormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('\s*(\+375|80)\s?-?\s?(25|29|33|44)\s?-?\s?\d{3}\s?-?\s?\d{2}\s?-?\s?\d{2}')]);
```

Comment: It is not a problem to have `^` and `$` in this pattern (though they are redundant in this context). At any rate, your current solution - `'\s*(\+375|80)\s?-?\s?(25|29|33|44)\s?-?\s?\d{3}\s?-?\s?\d{2}\s?-?\s?\d{2}'` - throws the same exception.